# Problem decompiling SWF to FLA using the sothink flash decompiler

Tags: flash, decompiling

My SWF, when decompiled with flash decompiler, is generating an empty FLA.
The flash object also makes use of an XML file which is not being exported along with the SWF object. What could be done to decompile properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried other flash decompilers and had the same result?

You could try OpenWorld's Flash Explorer or WinFlasm.

I believe there is a way to obfuscate your swf files so that they can not be decompiled properly, I know I've run across difficulties like that in the past.

And of course the disclaimer:
If you're trying to illegally crack open someone else's SWF file... don't do it. :)